# Training a Keras model with video input on a Macbook Pro 13 results in "Killed: 9" status

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

The end goal of the system is to classify video input. The training data consists of 1-2 second 1080x1920 video sequences, which are preprocessed by transforming RGB frames to grayscale and ensuring video sequences have the same length by padding with blank frames. A series of 3D convolution layers connected to a fully-connected network is used. The **problem** is that, when the model is trained by calling the **fit** method, **"Killed: 9"** is returned and the program stops executing. Here is the code being used:

```
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling3D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from pprint import pprint
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

import json
import os
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

class VideoClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, frames_per_sequence):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.frames_per_sequence = frames_per_sequence
        self.X = []
        self.Y = []
        self.training_classes = []
        self.vc = None

    def train_vc_model(self):
        """ Train the video classifier
        """
        # split data into trainining and test data
        print "Splitting data into training and test sets"
        validation_split = 0.2
        sample_count = len(self.X)
        X_train = self.X[0:int(round(sample_count*(1-validation_split)))]
        Y_train = self.Y[0:int(round(sample_count*(1-validation_split)))]
        X_test = self.X[int(round(sample_count*(1-validation_split))):-1]
        Y_test = self.Y[int(round(sample_count*(1-validation_split))):-1]

        # incrementally train model
        print "Training video classifier"
        self.vc.fit(x=X_train,
                    y=Y_train,
                    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                    batch_size=10,
                    nb_epoch=10,
                    verbose=2)
        score = self.vc.evaluate(x=X_test,
                                 y=Y_test,
                                 batch_size=10)
        print "Accuracy: {0:.2%}".format(scores[1]*100)

    def generate_vc_model(self):
        """ Builds the video classifier model
        """
        print "".join(["Generating video classifier model\n",
                       "-"*40])
        vc = Sequential()
        print " - Adding convolution layers"
        vc.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=32,
                             kernel_dim1=2,
                             kernel_dim2=2,
                             kernel_dim3=2,
                             border_mode="same",
                             input_shape=(1, self.frames_per_sequence, self.rows, self.columns),
                              activation="relu"))
        vc.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
        vc.add(Dropout(0.5))
        vc.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=32,
                             kernel_dim1=2,
                             kernel_dim2=2,
                             kernel_dim3=2,
                             border_mode="same",
                             activation="relu"))
        vc.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
        vc.add(Dropout(0.5))
        vc.add(Flatten())
        print " - Adding fully connected layers"
        vc.add(Dense(output_dim=32,
                     init="normal",
                     activation="relu"))
        vc.add(Dense(output_dim=32,
                     init="normal",
                     activation="relu"))
        vc.add(Dense(output_dim=3,
                     init="normal",
                     activation="softmax"))
        print " - Compiling model"
        sgd = SGD(lr=0.01,
                  decay=1e-6,
                  momentum=0.9,
                  nesterov=True)
        vc.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                    optimizer=sgd)
        self.vc = vc
        print " * VIDEO CLASSIFIER MODEL GENERATED * "

    def load_training_data(self):
        """ Loads and preprocesses training data
        """

        # load training metadata from config file
        training_metadata = {}
        training_classes = []
        with open("training_config.json") as training_config:
            training_metadata = json.load(training_config)
            training_classes = sorted(list(training_metadata.keys()))

            print "".join(["\n",
                           "Found {0} training classes!\n".format(len(training_classes)),
                           "-"*40])
            for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
                print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<30s}".format(class_label, training_class, training_metadata[training_class])
            print ""

        X, Y = self.preprocess_training_data(training_metadata, training_classes)
        X, Y = shuffle(X, Y)

        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.training_classes = training_classes

    def preprocess_training_data(self, training_metadata, training_classes):
        """ Preprocess training data for loading
        """
        # process training data
        X = []
        Y = []
        # iterate through each class data
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            # get training class sequeunce paths
            training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
            training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                             for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                             if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                                 and ".mov" in file_name)]
            # iterate through each sequence
            for idx, training_class_sequence_path in enumerate(training_class_sequence_paths):
                sys.stdout.write("Processing training data for class \"{0}\": {1}/{2} sequences\r".format(training_class, idx+1, len(training_class_sequence_paths)))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                # get frames
                frames = self.split_frames(training_class_sequence_path)
                # equalize sequence length
                if len(frames) < self.frames_per_sequence:
                    blank_frame = np.zeros((self.rows, self.columns))
                    for _ in xrange(self.frames_per_sequence - len(frames)):
                        frames.append(blank_frame)
                frames = frames[0:self.frames_per_sequence]
                frames = map(lambda frame: frame.astype("float32") / 255.0, frames)
                # add frames and class lable to training data
                X.append([frames])
                Y.append(class_label)
            print "\n"

        # one hot encode labels
        Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y)

        return X, Y

    def split_frames(self, video_file_path):
        """ Splits video sequences into frames
        """
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
        success, frame = video.read()

        frames = []
        success = True

        while success:
          success, frame = video.read()
          if success:
            frames.append(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

        return frames

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vc = VideoClassifier(1080, 1920, 30)
    vc.load_training_data()
    vc.generate_osr_model()
    vc.train_osr_model()
```

From what I understand, "Killed: 9" means that the program is consuming too much memory, and I only have 8 GB of RAM with my 13-inch Macbook Pro. I have tried reducing the batch size to 1, but even that does not solve the problem. Is there another way to train a Keras model to deal with this memory constraint?

Comment: I have never seen a convnet that classifies such a big image, the biggest is around 512x512. So just downscale your image to a sensible size.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I see. I will try resizing the images. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These images are just too big for classification, and recent research never goes beyond 512x512 images (mostly for object detection). For classification the typical sizes are around 256x256 or 224x224.

So your only option is to downscale the images to a reasonable size. Also reducing the batch size helps to reduce memory usage, but it won't work in this case.